# Listview with multiple images and text on single line in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-lazyadapter

hi i am going to make a to-do list so what i need is that to assign my task and view it as a list view in those list view need 3 text view and 3 images in this 3 images represent 3 activity like alarm, calendar and so on when i click these images its open seperatly i had i know to retrieve the data's from database to list view but did not know how to set multiple image in a single list.and make those images click able.now how can i do that i tried the lazy adaptor but it is used in the parsing phases there is no parsing in my application please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are many different post all over the place about creating custom ListView items. [this one](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter) is very helpfull and similar to what you want to do.

when working with images and ListViews, it's very important to implement Lazy image loading. the best implementation I know, is [ferdovlasove's LazyAdapter](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList).

enjoy...

Comment: that was a nice tutorial but how can i make that image click able?

Comment: since every image has an ID and you need to assign them (meaning you can access every image), you can add an `onClick` listener to each one

Comment: great i got it tank you bro :)